# Wordpress installation within Codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I have a website (http://nottingham.subverb.net) that is mainly made up of messy procedural code and then a wordpress installation in a sub-directory that is handles a number of blogs. The database has been manipulated to link the rest of the site and what-have-you

Now that I'd deem myself to be a better programmer than when I started it, I want to rewrite the whole lot in Codeigniter - except the wordpress installation. But I have no idea how I would replicate the lot as I cant just install wordpress in the controllers folder.

Ive not had much love from Codeigniter forums or google...does anyone know if this is even possible?

Basically I want to be able to install wordpress and have it function exactly as it is now in the domain.com/blog/ directory

Does this make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude your directory from the codeigniter url rewrite conditions in the .htaccess file.

If you want to have friendly urls in the wordpress installation you would need to add the wordpress rewrite conditions as well but relative to the path it is installed in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What directory would I then put it in? Would I just have it inside a directory /blog/ inside the root directory then, where the application and system folders are?

Comment: And the rewrite conditions, are they just rules that I can copy from wordpress and put into my htaccess or is this a really long winded process?

Comment: You can chose any directory just make sure you exclude it. /blog is fine. See this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510457/installing-codeigniter-on-root-and-wordpress-in-sub-directory). If you plan to use custom permalinks in you wordpress blog you need to add rules below the ones for excluding the /blog file. These rules are generated by wordpress when you enable custom permalinks.

Comment: @Michael Mallett: The sub directory's name can be whatever you like. The first group of rewrite rules Dimitris is referring to is part of the CI universe, which I'm not familiar with. The second group are the WP rules for SE-friendly URLS and those can/should live in the .htaccess file in the directory where WP is installed. I would suggest not mixing those two groups for several reasons, the primary one being simple cleanliness and separation.

Comment: Thankyou very much Peter and Dimitris