# Codeigniter in the root, Wordpress in a sub directory, but WP reading by default

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've read up on several posts here and elsewhere regarding very similar questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510457/installing-codeigniter-on-root-and-wordpress-in-sub-directory) probably being the closest). The catch with our situation is that I don't want WP to be a blog that is appended to our app, but rather the thing people see when they hit our URL. The problem, of course, being that Codeigniter, since it's in the root whilst WP is in `/wordpress/`, has its index.php in the root. For me to set WP up to read as root without it being such requires *it's* index.php to be in the root.

Any ideas besides moving our application portion into a new directory? Have tons of user activity at the moment that is mission critical so don't want to fool with potential downtime, conflicts, etc. Basically we want to not touch the app if at all possible and simply have people not logged in route to the WP marketing site without seeing /wordpress/ in the URL.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

> Basically we want to not touch the app if at all possible and simply **have people not logged in route to the WP marketing site** without seeing /wordpress/ in the URL.

If your main app handles authentication, you're probably using a cookie to store an authentication token. Your can use this cookie in your .htaccess in order to determine how the URL is rewritten. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if auth cookie is not set, use /wordpress/ routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*authcookiename.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wordpress/index.php/$1 [L]

# otherwise, use the codeigniter routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

There are two caveats:

1. This might cause issues with wordpress routes for static resources. You might need to finagle with some RewriteConds and the Wordpress config to make this work properly.
2. Assuming you aren't already, you need to edit config.php such that:

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: Ooo, didn't realize I could have htaccess check for that. Seems like a great solution. I'll give it a whirl later today or tomorrow and report back as to whether or not it solves. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Had a few customer fires and unexpected items crop up this week such that the above has been put on hold for the moment. Will get back to you as soon as implementation/testing can occur!