# Installing CodeIgniter on root and WordPress in sub-directory Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I installed wordpress in codeIngiter root directory, If I use wordpress permalinks then I am getting codeIgniter's 404 page not found error on wordpress pages.
my .htacess file is as follows. where I am getting wrong setting?  .htacess file. similar question is  [Installing CodeIgniter on root and WordPress in sub-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510457/installing-codeigniter-on-root-and-wordpress-in-sub-directory)

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.(js|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|swf|txt|xml|htc|pdf|xls|doc|ico)$

# Remove the index.php file
# Ref. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|blog|opensearch\.xml|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: make sure you have two .htaccess one is for wordpress and one is for code igniter, both have their own rule so when you call wordpress URL .htaccess of wordpress directory would get called.

Comment: yes. I have two .htacess files one is in root directory of CodeIgniter and second is in blog directory where wordpress is installed

Comment: in that case default configuration of both should work, can you please pass you htaccess to me?

Comment: root htacess -  http://pastebin.com/rS24MNJj
wordpress htacess - http://pastebin.com/09NDd4m4

Comment: this is what i was expecting, you should set proper rewrite base in htaccess of wordpress,

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: it should work, can you make sure the directory name in rewite base is correct, i mean it should be same as wordpress installation directory. @Ajinkya

Answer (score 0):

```
something like.

DirectoryIndex index.php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

see rewrite base how i have modified, and you now try to access both codeigniter and wordpress url

Comment: Not working !! :-(
 I think codeigniter htacess need some changes .