# Installed wordpress and codeigniter on same server root directory, 404 error for wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I installed WordPress and CodeIgniter on same server root directory when accessing codeigniter page it was working fine and even able to open wp-admin, but not able to open any page created in WordPress or blog post URL getting 404 error from CodeIgniter.

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510457/installing-codeigniter-on-root-and-wordpress-in-sub-directory

Comment: I think really you should install either WordPress into a subdirectory, or CodeIgniter into a subdirectory.  I can't imagine it's going to work properly having them both in the main document root.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the problem is one of the `index.php` files has been overwritten. In the below links that highlight the document structure, both have the `index.php` handle all of the routing and loading of the libraries. This also makes sense for your point about being able to open `/wp-admin/` since it's a different (sub) directory.

Additionally, the `.htaccess` files for the two may be different, depending on the settings, again, causing conflicts. As @MrCarrot mentioned in his comment, they should be in different directories.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-file-and-directory-structure/

https://selftaughtcoders.com/codeigniter-application-folder-structure-files/